# Upload minor version code to play store with fastlane

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, fastlane

I'm facing the `multiApkDowngradedDevice` error on fastlane supply and figured out this error is occurring 'cause I have an older versionName "3.6.02" with versionCode 3601 and now I'm trying to upload new versionCode 381 to play store. Doing the proccess manually everything works with not even a warning.

I'm using version `2.67.0` of fastlane.

Lane:

```
desc "Deploy a new beta version to the Google Play Store"
lane :deploy do
    gradle(
        task: 'assemble',
        flavor: 'sandbox', 
        build_type: 'Release'
    )
    sign_apk(
        keystore_path: "#{File.expand_path("..", Dir.pwd)}/key play_google/mykey",
        alias: "alias",
        storepass: "*****",
        keypass: "*****",
        signed_apk_path: "#{File.expand_path("..", Dir.pwd)}/app/sandbox.apk",
        tsa: "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc316"
    )
    zipalign(apk_path: lane_context[SharedValues::SIGNED_APK_PATH])
    supply(
        package_name: "com.app",
        track: "beta",
        skip_upload_screenshots: true,
        skip_upload_images: true,
        apk: lane_context[SharedValues::SIGNED_APK_PATH]
    )
end
```

Error:

> Google Api Error: multiApkDowngradedDevice: Devices with version 3602
>   of this app would be downgraded to version 381 if they met the
>   following criteria: [(API_LEVEL in range 16-0 AND RELEASE_TRACK
>   containing any of each of [[ALPHA, BETA]] AND SCREENS containing any
>   of each of [[small, normal, large, xlarge]] AND GL_ES_VERSION in range
>   131072-0 AND FEATURES containing all of
>   [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.FAKETOUCH,
>   android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.CAMERA,
>   android.hardware.WIFI])]

Comment: Please include the complete error mesage and lane/command you are running in your question for context.

Comment: edited @janpio . Lane and error message are in question

Comment: Interesting. The error message makes total sense, so it's strange the web UI lets you upload that apk at all.